# Copy/Display the html table with css as emailbody on click

Tags: javascript, mailto

Using simple JavaScript display the HTML table contents in the mail.

If we do a simple select all and copy the HTML selected content and paste in the mail, it works. Same done using JavaScript cannot be replicated.

```
  var email = 'xyz@abc.com';
  var subject = "Table Template"
  var contentDiv = document.getElementById('content');
  var emailBody = contentDiv.textContent;
  window.location = 'mailto:' + email + '?subject=' + subject + '&body=' + emailBody;
```

[Email - JavaScript](https://plnkr.co/edit/BfO09hHJGlob7L2EfV8t?p=preview)

Answer (score 0):

`mailto:` is a loose spec and is entirely based on mail client support. You will never be guaranteed that HTML will work in the body. In fact, always assume it won't.

The reason it works with copy/paste is because your specific web browser, operating system, and mail client are communicating in a different manner that has nothing to do with HTML.